# Heroku error: "Could not find an executable ["phantomjs"] on your path."

Tags: ruby, heroku, phantomjs, buildpack

I get an error when I run `ruby bin/test.rb` in the heroku console

### Error

```
"Could not find an executable ["phantomjs"] on your path."
```

I have two files:
bin/test.rb and Gemfile

### Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'capybara'
gem 'poltergeist'
gem 'mail'
gem 'rmagick'
```

I ran

```
 heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/stomita/heroku-buildpack-phantomjs.git
```

I ran

```
 heroku config:set PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/app/vendor/phantomjs/bin"
```

I'm not sure of the path for phantonJS or where the build pack puts it.
How to I fix this error?

Comment: Despite requiring `phantomjs/poltergeist` in my Gemfile, I had to follow https://github.com/colszowka/phantomjs-gem#manual-setup to fix this error for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do a recommit on Heroku to get it working.  Bundle install and restart was not enough.